# HID Device programming - Does it works with C++ (SETUPAPI.dll and HID.dll)

Tags: c++, dll, device-driver, hid, setupapi

I'm kinda new in asking @Stackoverflow, however it's been the closest thing I have as a Bible (other than Ritchie's C book) specially in these days of final projects for most of my subjects. Anyway, my question is about the libraries needed for an application that communicates with a HID Device and the possibility to do it with C++.

I don't need help with the Firmware, my device is already working the way I expect it to. However my only experience programming HID devices is with **C** (Windows - VS2010) and right now I am in a final project for Compilers class in wich we send information to a device with a matrix screen to display "stuff". My partner however needs to do something in **C++** which can save us a lot of time (something nice considering its due in two days).

The whole point of this being to ask if it can be done the same way that I already have in **C** (with its obvious adjustments) and some parts of the code in **C++** and still get to be compatible with SetupApi.DLL and HID.DLL

Any kind of advice, pointers or instructions is deeply appreciated. I include the code I have used so far.

***Excuse all the comments in spanish and mess I might have***

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <SETUPAPI.H>

//----------------------------------------------

#define RICH_VENDOR_ID      0x0000
#define RICH_USBHID_GENIO_ID    0x2012

#define INPUT_REPORT_SIZE   5
#define OUTPUT_REPORT_SIZE  2
//----------------------------------------------
char c=0x0;
DWORD BytesRead = 0;
DWORD BytesWritten = 0;
unsigned char reporteEntrada[INPUT_REPORT_SIZE+1];
unsigned char reporteSalida[OUTPUT_REPORT_SIZE+1];
int status = 0;
static unsigned char dato = 0x01;
static unsigned char numLED = 1;
unsigned char palabra[192]={0};
int desplegar,valorled;
desplegar=0;
valorled=0;
unsigned char temporal;
//unsigned char ch;
//unsigned int index;
typedef struct _HIDD_ATTRIBUTES {
    ULONG   Size; // = sizeof (struct _HIDD_ATTRIBUTES)
    USHORT  VendorID;
    USHORT  ProductID;
    USHORT  VersionNumber;
} HIDD_ATTRIBUTES, *PHIDD_ATTRIBUTES;

typedef VOID    (__stdcall *PHidD_GetProductString)(HANDLE, PVOID, ULONG);
typedef VOID    (__stdcall *PHidD_GetHidGuid)(LPGUID);
typedef BOOLEAN (__stdcall *PHidD_GetAttributes)(HANDLE, PHIDD_ATTRIBUTES);
typedef BOOLEAN (__stdcall *PHidD_SetFeature)(HANDLE, PVOID, ULONG);
typedef BOOLEAN (__stdcall *PHidD_GetFeature)(HANDLE, PVOID, ULONG);

//----------------------------------------------

HINSTANCE                       hHID                    = NULL;
PHidD_GetProductString          HidD_GetProductString   = NULL;
PHidD_GetHidGuid                HidD_GetHidGuid         = NULL;
PHidD_GetAttributes             HidD_GetAttributes      = NULL;
PHidD_SetFeature                HidD_SetFeature         = NULL;
PHidD_GetFeature                HidD_GetFeature         = NULL;
HANDLE                          DeviceHandle            = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;

unsigned int moreHIDDevices=TRUE;
unsigned int HIDDeviceFound=FALSE;

unsigned int terminaAbruptaEInstantaneamenteElPrograma=0;

void Load_HID_Library (void) {
    hHID = LoadLibrary("HID.DLL");
    if (!hHID) {
        printf("Failed to load HID.DLL\n");
        return;
    }

    HidD_GetProductString = (PHidD_GetProductString) GetProcAddress(hHID, "HidD_GetProductString");
    HidD_GetHidGuid       = (PHidD_GetHidGuid) GetProcAddress(hHID, "HidD_GetHidGuid");
    HidD_GetAttributes    = (PHidD_GetAttributes) GetProcAddress(hHID, "HidD_GetAttributes");
    HidD_SetFeature       = (PHidD_SetFeature) GetProcAddress(hHID, "HidD_SetFeature");
    HidD_GetFeature       = (PHidD_GetFeature) GetProcAddress(hHID, "HidD_GetFeature");

    if (   !HidD_GetProductString
        || !HidD_GetAttributes
        || !HidD_GetHidGuid
        || !HidD_SetFeature
        || !HidD_GetFeature ) {
        printf("Couldn't find one or more HID entry points\n");
        return;
    }
}

int Open_Device(void) {
    HDEVINFO                            DeviceInfoSet;
    GUID                                InterfaceClassGuid;
    SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA            DeviceInterfaceData;
    PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA    pDeviceInterfaceDetailData;
    HIDD_ATTRIBUTES                     Attributes;  
    DWORD                               Result;
    DWORD                               MemberIndex = 0;
    DWORD                               Required;

    //Validar si se "cargó" la biblioteca (DLL)
    if (!hHID)
        return (0);

    //Obtener el Globally Unique Identifier (GUID) para dispositivos HID
    HidD_GetHidGuid (&InterfaceClassGuid);
    //Sacarle a Windows la información sobre todos los dispositivos HID instalados y activos en el sistema
    // ... almacenar esta información en una estructura de datos de tipo HDEVINFO
    DeviceInfoSet = SetupDiGetClassDevs(&InterfaceClassGuid, NULL, NULL, DIGCF_PRESENT|DIGCF_INTERFACEDEVICE);
    if (DeviceInfoSet == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return (0);

    //Obtener la interfaz de comunicación con cada uno de los dispositivos para preguntarles información específica
    DeviceInterfaceData.cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA);
    while (!HIDDeviceFound) {
        // ... utilizando la variable MemberIndex ir preguntando dispositivo por dispositivo ...
        moreHIDDevices = SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces (DeviceInfoSet, NULL, &InterfaceClassGuid,
                                                                        MemberIndex,&DeviceInterfaceData);
        if (!moreHIDDevices) {
            // ... si llegamos al fin de la lista y no encontramos al dispositivo ==> terminar y marcar error
            SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(DeviceInfoSet);    
            return (0); //No more devices found
        } else {
            //Necesitamos preguntar, a través de la interfaz, el PATH del dispositivo, para eso ...
            // ... primero vamos a ver cuántos caracteres se requieren (Required)
            Result = SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(DeviceInfoSet,&DeviceInterfaceData,NULL,0,&Required,NULL);
            pDeviceInterfaceDetailData = (PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA)malloc(Required);
            if (pDeviceInterfaceDetailData == NULL) {
                printf("Error en SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail\n");
                return (0);
            }
            //Ahora si, ya que el "buffer" fue preparado (pDeviceInterfaceDetailData{DevicePath}), vamos a preguntar PATH
            pDeviceInterfaceDetailData->cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA);
            Result = SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail (DeviceInfoSet,&DeviceInterfaceData,pDeviceInterfaceDetailData,
                                                                                                    Required,NULL,NULL);
            if (!Result) {
                printf("Error en SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail\n");
                free(pDeviceInterfaceDetailData);
                return(0);
            }
            //Para este momento ya sabemos el PATH del dispositivo, ahora hay que preguntarle ...
            // ... su VID y PID, para ver si es con quien nos interesa comunicarnos
            printf("Found? ==> ");
            printf("Device: %s\n",pDeviceInterfaceDetailData->DevicePath);

            //Obtener un "handle" al dispositivo
            DeviceHandle = CreateFile (pDeviceInterfaceDetailData->DevicePath,
                                    GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE,
                                    FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                                    (LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES)NULL,
                                    OPEN_EXISTING,
                                    0,
                                    NULL);

            if (DeviceHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
                printf("¡¡¡Error en el CreateFile!!!\n");
            } else {
                //Preguntar por los atributos del dispositivo
                Attributes.Size = sizeof(Attributes);
                Result = HidD_GetAttributes (DeviceHandle,&Attributes);
                if (!Result) {
                    printf("Error en HIdD_GetAttributes\n");
                    CloseHandle(DeviceHandle);
                    free(pDeviceInterfaceDetailData);
                    return(0);
                }
                //Analizar los atributos del dispositivo para verificar el VID y PID
                printf("MemberIndex=%d,VID=%04x,PID=%04x\n",MemberIndex,Attributes.VendorID,Attributes.ProductID);
                if ((Attributes.VendorID == RICH_VENDOR_ID) && (Attributes.ProductID == RICH_USBHID_GENIO_ID)) {
                    printf("USB/HID GenIO ==> ");
                    printf("Device: %s\n",pDeviceInterfaceDetailData->DevicePath);
                    HIDDeviceFound=TRUE;
                } else
                    CloseHandle(DeviceHandle);    

            }
            MemberIndex++;
            free(pDeviceInterfaceDetailData);
            if (HIDDeviceFound) {
                printf("Dispositivo HID solicitado ... ¡¡¡localizado!!!, presione <ENTER>\n");
                getchar();
            }
        }
    }
    return(1);
}

void Close_Device (void) {
    if (DeviceHandle != NULL) {
        CloseHandle(DeviceHandle);
        DeviceHandle = NULL;
    }
}

int chToIndex(unsigned char ch){
    if((ch>='0')&&(ch<='9')){
        return ch-48;
    }else if((ch>='A')&&(ch<='Z')){
        return ch-55;
    }else if((ch>='a')&&(ch<='z')){
        return ch-61;
    }else{
        switch (ch){
        case '*': return 62;
        //  break;
        case '+': return 63;
        //  break;
        case '-': return 64;
            //break;
        case '/': return 65;
            //break;
        case '=': return 66;
        //  break;
        case '>': return 67;
        //  break;
        case '<': return 68;
        //  break;
        case '!': return 69;
        //  break;
        case '.': return 70;
        //  break;
        case '&': return 71;
        //  break;
        case '^': return 72;
        //  break;
        case '(': return 73;
        //  break;
        case ')': return 74;
        //  break;
        case '[': return 75;
        //  break;
        case ']': return 76;
        //  break;
        case ',': return 77;
        //  break;
        case ';': return 78;
        //  break;
        case ':': return 79;
        //  break;
        case 0x20: return 80;
        default: return 81;
        //  break;
        }
    }


}
int Touch_Device (void) {
    int z;
    int index;
    int col,lin;
    unsigned char ch;

    if (DeviceHandle == NULL)   //Validar que haya comunicacion con el dispositivo
        return 0;

        if(c != '27' )
        {
            printf("Selecciona accion:\n1) Limpiar Pantalla\n2) Imprimir todos caracteres\n3) Escribir caracter\n4) Escribir string\n5) Salir\n");
            desplegar=getch();
            desplegar=getch();
            if((desplegar=='5')||(desplegar==(char)'27')){
                terminaAbruptaEInstantaneamenteElPrograma=1;
            }
            else if(desplegar=='4'){
                lin=0;
                col=0;
                index=0;
                printf("Escribe texto (termina con Enter):\n");
                scanf("%s",palabra);
                while(palabra[index]!='\0'){
                    z++;
                }
                printf("Longitud de palabra: %d",z);
                while((palabra[index]!='\0')){
                    if((palabra[index]==NULL)&&(palabra[index+1]!=NULL))
                        palabra[index]=0x20;
                    reporteSalida[0]=0x00;
                    reporteSalida[1]=0x04;
                    reporteSalida[2]=(char)chToIndex(palabra[index]);
                    reporteSalida[3]=(char)lin;
                    reporteSalida[4]=(char)col;
                    status = WriteFile(DeviceHandle,reporteSalida,INPUT_REPORT_SIZE+1,&BytesWritten,NULL);
                    if (!status)
                        printf("Error en el WriteFile %d %d\n",GetLastError(),BytesWritten);
                    else
                        printf("Se enviaron %d bytes al dispositivo (posX=%d, posY=%d, dato=%d)\n",BytesWritten,reporteSalida[4],reporteSalida[3],reporteSalida[2]);
                    if(col>=23){
                        lin++;
                        col=0;
                    }
                    if(lin>=7){
                        lin=0;
                    }
                    col++;
                    index++;
                }
            }
            else if (desplegar=='3'){
                reporteSalida[0]=0x00;
                reporteSalida[1]=0x04;
                printf("Que caracter deseas desplegar: ");
                ch=getch();
                printf("\n");
                z=chToIndex(ch);
                reporteSalida[2]=(char)z;
                do{
                printf("En que renglon en y (0-7): ");
                scanf("%d",&desplegar);
                printf("\n");
                }while((desplegar<0)&&(desplegar>7));
                reporteSalida[3]=(char)desplegar;
                do{
                printf("En que columna en x (0-23): ");
                scanf("%d",&desplegar);
                printf("\n");
                }while((desplegar<0)&&(desplegar>23));
                reporteSalida[4]=(char)desplegar;
                printf("ReporteSalida: %02X %02X %02X %02X %02X \n",(unsigned char)reporteSalida[0],
                    (unsigned char)reporteSalida[1],
                    (unsigned char)reporteSalida[2],
                    (unsigned char)reporteSalida[3],
                    (unsigned char)reporteSalida[4]);

                status = WriteFile(DeviceHandle,reporteSalida,INPUT_REPORT_SIZE+1,&BytesWritten,NULL);
                if (!status)
                    printf("Error en el WriteFile %d %d\n",GetLastError(),BytesWritten);
                else
                    printf("Se enviaron %d bytes al dispositivo (posX=%d, posY=%d, dato=%d)\n",BytesWritten,reporteSalida[4],reporteSalida[3],reporteSalida[2]);

            }
            else if (desplegar=='2'){
                lin=0;
                col=0;
                for (index=0;index<=80;index++){
                    reporteSalida[0]=0x00;
                    reporteSalida[1]=0x04;
                    reporteSalida[2]=(char)index;
                    reporteSalida[3]=(char)lin;
                    reporteSalida[4]=(char)col;
                    status = WriteFile(DeviceHandle,reporteSalida,INPUT_REPORT_SIZE+1,&BytesWritten,NULL);
                    if (!status)
                        printf("Error en el WriteFile %d %d\n",GetLastError(),BytesWritten);
                    else
                        printf("Se enviaron %d bytes al dispositivo (posX=%d, posY=%d, dato=%d)\n",BytesWritten,reporteSalida[4],reporteSalida[3],reporteSalida[2]);
                    if(col>=23){
                        lin++;
                        col=0;
                    }
                    if(lin>=7){
                        lin=0;
                    }
                    col++;
                }
            }
            else if(desplegar=='1'){
                printf("Limpiando pantalla ...\n");
                reporteSalida[0]=0x00;
                reporteSalida[1]=0x03;
                reporteSalida[2]=0;
                status = WriteFile(DeviceHandle,reporteSalida,INPUT_REPORT_SIZE+1,&BytesWritten,NULL);
                if (!status)
                    printf("Error en el WriteFile %d %d\n",GetLastError(),BytesWritten);
                else
                    printf("Escritos %d\n",BytesWritten);
            }
            else{
                Touch_Device();
            }
        }
    return status;
}

void main () {
    Load_HID_Library();
    if (Open_Device()) {
        printf("Vamos bien\n");
        while ((c=getch()!=27)
            &&(!terminaAbruptaEInstantaneamenteElPrograma)) {
                Touch_Device();
                Sleep(500);
        }

    } else {
        printf(">:(\n");
    }
    Close_Device();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By and large, you can compile any C code as C++. Have you tried to compile it as C++ and did you get any errors?

The answer to your question is that, yes, you can use SETUPAPI.DLL and HID.DLL from C++ exactly as you would with C.

Comment: Well, but is there anything to take into account other than some functions? I have no experience whatsoever with C++, I have only worked with C, and to my disgrace Java.

Comment: You can view C++ as being C with extra features. Same syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Change your C source file into C++. If you are using VS, it could be as easy as change the file extension (.c -> .cpp) and fix some warning issues.

---

C++ programs can use setupapi.dll (C library) because APIs are declared like below.

(In the header file)

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

int declaration_of_c_function(...);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

extern "C" is the new syntax introduced in C++ to enable C/C++ integration.

That is, it not simple if you don't know C++.